# Print stars - one per line up to 5 using the for loop (python)

Tags: python

I'm very new to programming but trying to read and teach myself to see if this is really the profession I would like to pursue before actually taking a class. any help is appreciated.  this is what I have so far..

```
# print a line of stars count times.

def print_stars(count):
    x=5
    for i in range(x+1):
        print_stars(5)
        print(print_stars)
```

should look like this

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you would like something like this:

```
def print_stars(count):
    for i in range(1, count):
        print('*' * i)

print_stars(10)
```

`for i in range(1, count)` will give `1, 2, 3, 4...count`(count is a number like `10`).

And about `print('*' * i)`, first `'*'` is a string, that will be print.

And the second `*` means **plus**. `string * number` will print `string` *number* times.

**Demo:**

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
```

And your code will do something like:

```
for i in range(6):
    print_stars(5) # this will call the function itself, then make a endless loop
    print(print_stars) # '<function a at 0x7f73d3590ea0>' or something like this
```

Comment: Because he is new to programming you could give a short explanation whats the difference to his code and what's `str.__mul__`?

Comment: @HelloWorld Well, about `str.__mul__` I know usage. `'*'.__mul__(8)` will print something like `'********'`. But I don't know how does it works and how to explain it. Could you help me edit my answer and explain this?

Comment: Your answer is totally fine. `xxx.__mul__` is the function that is executed when `*` is used on the object like you did with your string. `"Foo" * 3` calls `str.__mul__`. Same for [__ add __](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.__add__) , [__ sub __](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.__sub__), ...

Comment: @HelloWorld Thanks, let me add them to my answer ;)

Comment: @HelloWorld All right, what do you think about this?

Comment: @HelloWorld Well, if you was mean this, because his is new to programming, I think that this will confused him. However I've just rollback to my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best approach but I think I have found a way to get the result you want.
try this `for-loop`:

```
for i in range(count):
    print('*' * i)
```

In this case you would take the count from your main code like needed. keep in mind as it starts from zero to stop at 5 stars you would need to set count to 6.

ps: I know it is very similar to the other answer in the question, but I thought I would add the part where the count starts from zero.